# Eclipse IDE for C++ not installing on mac

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, jvm

I am currently trying to download a version of the Eclipse IDE that will work with C++ on a Mac. I have a version that runs Java and works perfectly fine. When I try to install the version with CDT for C++ it gives me an error that says the JVM is not up to date. I have tried reinstalling a new Java version, and when verifying the version, Oracle tells me that my Java is up to date. Eclipse is telling me I need the 1.7 version, even though that is what I downloaded. Any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated, I really have no clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing through an update site?
The steps are something like Help > Install new Software > Add, and then enter the following in the location (and whatever you want in the name)
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.8

Comment: Jarrett is onto something there. No need to have two Eclipses. Run the eclipse you do have installed, from the main menu go Help->Install New Software. In the dialog that pop up, select Mars from the Work with dropdown and wait for the repository to load. Expand the Programming Languages tree and put a check in the C/C++ Development tools box. Add any other tools you think you'll want. Then probably all you have to do is click finish and read and accept some legal boilerplate.

Comment: Make sure you have the JDK installed not just the JRE. A JRE only install does not change the default Java on the Mac.

Comment: @user4581301 ok I did all of that and all of the tools have downloaded. When eclipse restarted, it automatically popped up in a Java workspace. How can I switch to the C++ developer? I have never worked with eclipse before so I'm quite confused.

Comment: In the top right hand corner between the Quick Access text input box and the Perspective button (should be labelled Java) is the Open Perspective button.It should look like a program screen with a plus in the top right corner. Click the Open Perspective button and select C/C++ from the dialog that pops up.